# How to execute init or woocommerce_init only for checkout page

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, pluggable, init

I am making extra function for my own project.

```
function devsol_customer_login() { 
if ( is_checkout() ) {  ?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" />
    <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
</form>
    <?php
    $user_phone = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['username'] );
    if ( $user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_phone) ) {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        $user_roles = $user->roles;
        $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
        if ( $user_role === 'customer') {
        echo 'Yes Customer';
            if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_auth_new_customer', true, $user_id ) ) {  
                wc_set_customer_auth_cookie( $user_id );
                }   
            }
        }   
    echo 'Home';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'devsol_customer_login');
```

But the function is not executing on checkout page. Can someone help

Comment: it's better to not create a new question but to add details in the first question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355571/function-not-executing-in-woocommerce-my-account-page

Comment: Conditional tags (like `is_home()`, `is_checkout()`, etc.) are only available after the `parse_query` action hook, which in turn is executed later than the `init` hook (`woocommerce_init` is executed by `init`). In other words: at the moment when the `woocommerce_init` hook is executed, the conditional tags **do not yet work**.

Comment: @nmr Thanks for details, If i didn't call init or woocommerce_init then i get header already sent error, any solution please

Comment: Specify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @nmr I am creating a function where i can put customer username and click login and customer account has been logged in without password. When I run this function without init it give me header already sent error. Actually I want to run init or woocommerce init only on checkout page instead of executing on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

At first I will notice that logging in with the username only sounds like a insecure solution .

You should not display the form in the `init` action hook. Add form display function
to the action hook from checkout page (e.g. [`woocommerce_before_checkout_form`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)) 
or [overwrite the checkout template](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) in the active theme and insert the form there.

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
{
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_attr( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="custsign" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'customer_signin' ); ?>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" 
            name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" 
            value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" 
            name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

Process the form (data validation, logging in, redirection) in the [`admin_post_nopriv_{action}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_nopriv_action/) action hook. It is recommended to add nonce to the form.

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_custsign', 'customer_login');
function customer_login()
{
    $return_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    if ( !isset( $_POST['username'] ) || empty($_POST['username']) ) 
        wp_redirect( $return_url );

    $nonce = wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'customer_signin' );
    if ( false === $nonce )
    {
        // invalid nonce
        wp_redirect( $return_url );
    }
    else {
        $uname = sanitize_user( $_POST['username'], true );
        $uid = username_exists( $uname );
        //
        // your permission checking code
        //
        if ( $uid !== false )
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $uid );
    }
    // back to order
    wp_redirect( $return_url );
}
```

By adding "nonce" to the form, which is sent by an unlogged user, you will probably need to use the `nonce_user_logged_out` action hook for verification to work. Attach to this hook a function that returns a value instead of the user ID. Due to the Woocommerce, ID of the unlogged user when calculating the nonce will not be the same in `admin_post_nopriv_{$action}` and displayed form.

```
add_filter ( 'nonce_user_logged_out', 'unlogged_user_nonce', 20, 2 );
function unlogged_user_nonce( $uid, $action )
{
    if ( 'customer_signin' == $action)
    {
        // generate returned value, for example:
        //
        // $uid = hash( 'sha1', $action );
        // 
    }
    return $uid;
}
```